# Setting other styles via JavaScript works fine, but how can I set font-family?

Tags: javascript, css

For example, on [this page](http://ascii.textfiles.com/archives/5139), opening the JS console in DevTools and running:

```
document.body.style.color = 'purple'
```

Sets the `color` to purple. The style is obviously applied and is visible in DevTools as `element.style`. But running:

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Georgia,Cambria,Times New Roman,Times,serif'
```

**Update:** even removing the typo (extra semi colon) has no effect.

**Update:** scratch that. I made a mistake. Please delete the question. I've already deleted my incorrect answer

Doesn't work. The style is not applied and is not visible in DevTools under `element-style`.

Why isn't setting `fontFamily` working? How can I change the font using JavaScript?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but it *should* be closed due to it being caused by a simple typo.

Comment: Nevermind, I made a mistake. Please delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `semicolon` inside quotes makes conflict.So Remove `semicolon`;

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Georgia,Cambria,Times New Roman,Times,serif';
```

**Example:**

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');
p.style.fontFamily = 'Georgia,Cambria,Times New Roman,Times,serif';
```

```html
<p>Test Font Familt</p>
```